# Property of model to return iterable to template

Tags: django

Say I have a model with a property that returns a dictionary. How do I iterate through it in the template? And how do I access values? Will I only get a boring string thing `{'':"",'':"",...}` to work with in the template? Or, heaven forbid, should the property return HTML?

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...
    @property
    def bar(self):
        # ...
        return aDictionary
```

And the imagined usage in a template...

```
{{ foo.bar['key'] }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property values should be accessible using the dot notation:

```
{{ foo.bar.key }}
```

Assuming:

```
@property
def bar(self):
    return {'key':'value'}
```

your template should render `value`.

*Update as suggested by OP:*

To loop on the dictionary key/values at template level use:

```
{% for k, v in foo.bar.items %}
```

as in for example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    {% for k, v in foo.bar.items %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{k}}</td>
        <td>{{v}}</td>
    </tr>
    {%endfor%}
</table>
</ul>
```

Relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#variables).

Comment: And how would I iterate through them? `for key, value in foo.bar` is not working....

Comment: @broinjc Not sure, try to loop over `foo.bar.keys`; again I'm unsure.

Comment: I figured it out and updated your answer. It was `foo.bar.items`

Comment: @broinjc Excuse me for overwriting your edit; I noticed that I had lost the latter part of my answer as your edit came in too quickly. But I see you suggested another edit; are you sure that's correct? Three editors already marked it as incorrect. I just "skipped" approving/rejecting it as I'm unsure.

Comment: It works correctly for me.`foos = Foo.objects.all()` and then `for foo in foos: for k,v in foo.bar.items:`

Comment: "iterable" is in the question title, so I thought it would be worth having a code snippet for that in the answer.

Comment: @broinjc Does that syntax work at template level though? Because I'm sure it works server-side. But you ask for a template level solution.

Comment: Oh! Not the syntax in the comment, the syntax I edited into your post. `{% for n in foo.bar.items %}`

Comment: @broinjc So `{% for k, v in foo.bar.items %} Key:{{k}} Value:{{v}} {%endfor%}` works at template level? Please confirm.

Comment: Yes. And the view code is `foo = get_object_or_404(Foo, pk=1)`

Comment: both `items` and `iteritems` works for me. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#variables